# Why is my app returning to the email verification screen after a succcessful logout?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, bloc

In my Flutter app, I'm trying to implement email verification on registration with BLoC and Firebase. When I register a user, and then attempt to sign out in the app with that user, the app returns to the email verification screen, instead of to the login screen.

I have an Authentication Service class which manages all firebase interactions, and I have an authentication bloc which calls methods from this class depending on what actions a user takes.

authentication.dart

```
class AuthService {

  // creating a member of class that represents an instance of firebase authentication
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // create user object based on firebase User class
  AppUser? userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    // ternary operator
    return AppUser(
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      isVerified: user.emailVerified
    );
  }

  Future refreshCurrentUser() async {
    await auth.currentUser?.reload();
  }

  Stream<AppUser> retrieveCurrentUser() {
    // listening to when a user signs in/out
    // mapping firebase User to AppUser
    return auth.authStateChanges().map((User? user) {
      if (user != null) {
        return AppUser(uid: user.uid, email: user.email, isVerified: user.emailVerified);
      } else {
        return  AppUser(uid: "uid", email: "email", isVerified: false);
      }
    });
  }

  // sign in anonymously
  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await auth.signInAnonymously();
      User? firebaseUser = result.user;
      return userFromFirebaseUser(firebaseUser!);
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    
    }
  }

  // sign in with email & password
  Future<AppUser?> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      User? firebaseUser = result.user;
      return userFromFirebaseUser(firebaseUser!);
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  // register with email & password
  Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      User? firebaseUser = result.user;
      return userFromFirebaseUser(firebaseUser!);
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> sendVerificationEmail() async {
    
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null && !user.emailVerified) {
      print('sendVerificationEmail()');
      return await user.sendEmailVerification();
    }
  }

  // sign out
  Future signOutFunc() async {
    try {
      auth.signOut();
    } catch(e) {
      print('Failed to sign out');
      print(e);

    }
  }

  Future<void> deleteUser() async {
    try {
      User user = auth.currentUser!;
      user.delete();
      print('deleted accocunt: ${user.email}');
    } catch(e) {
      print('Failed to delete user');
    }
  }
}
```

authentication_bloc.dart

```
class AuthenticationBloc
    extends Bloc<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  Timer? _emailVerificationTimer;
  Timer? _emailVerificationLifetimeTimer;

  AuthenticationBloc() : super(AuthenticationInitialState()) {
    on<AuthenticationInitialEvent>(authenticationInitialEvent);
    on<AuthenticationLoginButtonClickedEvent>(
        authenticationLoginButtonClickedEvent);
    on<AuthenticationRegisterButtonClickedEvent>(
        authenticationRegisterButtonClickedEvent);
    on<AuthenticationLogoutButtonClickedEvent>(
        authenticationLogoutButtonClickedEvent);
    on<AuthenticationSwitchScreenButtonClickedEvent>(
        authenticationSwitchScreenClickedEvent);
    on<AuthenticationInitialEmailVerificationEvent>(
        authenticationInitialEmailVerificationEvent);
    on<AuthenticationCheckEmailVerificationStatusEvent>(
        authenticationCheckEmailVerificationStatusEvent);
    on<AuthenticationTimerExpiredEvent>(authenticationTimerExpiredEvent);
    on<AuthenticationRegistrationCancelledEvent>(
        authenticationRegistrationCancelledEvent);
    on<AuthenticationDeleteAccountEvent>(authenticationDeleteAccountEvent);
  }

  void authenticationInitialEvent(AuthenticationInitialEvent event,
      Emitter<AuthenticationState> emit) async {
    print('authenticationInitialEvent()');
    try {
      emit(AuthenticationLoadingState());

      final currentUser = await _auth.retrieveCurrentUser().first;
      print(currentUser.uid);
      if (currentUser.uid != "uid") {
        print('authenticationSuccessState()');
        emit(AuthenticationSuccessState(user: currentUser));
      } else {
        print('authenticationFailureState()');
        emit(AuthenticationFailureState(
            errorMessage: 'Provided user credentials are invalid.'));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      emit(AuthenticationFailureState(errorMessage: 'Authentication process.'));
    }
  }

  void authenticationLoginButtonClickedEvent(
      AuthenticationLoginButtonClickedEvent event,
      Emitter<AuthenticationState> emit) async {
    print('authenticationLoginButtonClickedEvent()');

    if (validFormFieldsLogin(event.email, event.password) == false) {
      emit(AuthenticationFormErrorState());
      return;
    }

    try {
      emit(AuthenticationLoadingState());

      final user = await _auth.signIn(event.email, event.password);
      if (user != null) {
        print('${user.email} : ${user.uid}');
        emit(AuthenticationSuccessState(user: user));
      } else {
        emit(AuthenticationFailureState(
            errorMessage: 'Invalid email or password'));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      emit(AuthenticationFailureState(errorMessage: 'Failed to login'));
    }
  }

  void authenticationLogoutButtonClickedEvent(
      AuthenticationLogoutButtonClickedEvent event,
      Emitter<AuthenticationState> emit) async {
    print('authenticationLogoutButtonClickedEvent()');
    try {
      emit(AuthenticationLoadingState());
      stopEmailVerificationTimers();

      await _auth.signOutFunc();
      emit(AuthenticationLogoutSuccessState());
    } catch (e) {
      emit(AuthenticationFailureState(errorMessage: 'Failed to logout'));
    }
  }

  FutureOr<void> authenticationSwitchScreenClickedEvent(
      AuthenticationSwitchScreenButtonClickedEvent event,
      Emitter<AuthenticationState> emit) {
    print('authenticationSwitchScreenClickedEvent');
    emit(AuthenticationSwitchScreenState());
  }

  FutureOr<void> authenticationRegisterButtonClickedEvent(
      AuthenticationRegisterButtonClickedEvent event,
      Emitter<AuthenticationState> emit) async {
    print('authenticationRegisterButtonClickedEvent()');

    // checking form for basic user input mistakes
    if (validFormFieldsRegister(event.email, event.password, event.confirmPassword) == false) {
      emit(AuthenticationFormErrorState());
      return;
    }

    try {
      emit(AuthenticationLoadingState());
      // creating user
      final user =
          await _auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword(event.email, event.password);
      if (user != null) {
        // going to email verification screen
        emit(AuthenticationNavigateToEmailVerificationState(user: user));
      } else {
        emit(AuthenticationFailureState(errorMessage: 'Failed to register'));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      emit(AuthenticationFailureState(errorMessage: 'Failed to register'));
    }
  }

  void startEmailVerification() async {
    print('startEmailVerification()');
    _auth.sendVerificationEmail();
    _emailVerificationLifetimeTimer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 30), () {
      print('Lifetime timer finished');
      add(AuthenticationTimerExpiredEvent());
    });
    // Adjust the interval as needed
    _emailVerificationTimer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), (_) {
      add(AuthenticationCheckEmailVerificationStatusEvent());
    });
  }

  FutureOr<void> authenticationCheckEmailVerificationStatusEvent(
      AuthenticationCheckEmailVerificationStatusEvent event,
      Emitter<AuthenticationState> emit) async {
    print('authenticationCheckEmailVerificationStatusEvent()');

    _auth.refreshCurrentUser();
    final currentUserStream = _auth.retrieveCurrentUser();

    await for (final user in currentUserStream) {
      print({user.email, user.isVerified});

      if (user.isVerified) {
        // Email is verified
        stopEmailVerificationTimers();
        emit(AuthenticationSuccessState(user: user));
        break;
      } else {
        emit(AuthenticationEmailVerificationInProgressState(user: user));
      }
    }
  }

  FutureOr<void> authenticationInitialEmailVerificationEvent(
      AuthenticationInitialEmailVerificationEvent event,
      Emitter<AuthenticationState> emit) async {
    startEmailVerification();
  }

  FutureOr<void> authenticationTimerExpiredEvent(
      AuthenticationTimerExpiredEvent event,
      Emitter<AuthenticationState> emit) async {
    stopEmailVerificationTimers();
    // delete user
    // _auth.deleteUser();
    emit(AuthenticationRegistrationFailedState());
  }

  FutureOr<void> authenticationRegistrationCancelledEvent(
      AuthenticationRegistrationCancelledEvent event,
      Emitter<AuthenticationState> emit) {
    stopEmailVerificationTimers();
    // delete user
    // _auth.deleteUser();
    emit(AuthenticationRegistrationFailedState());
  }

  void stopEmailVerificationTimers() {
    print('stopEmailVerificationTimers()');
    _emailVerificationTimer?.cancel();
    _emailVerificationLifetimeTimer?.cancel();
  }

  FutureOr<void> authenticationDeleteAccountEvent(
      AuthenticationDeleteAccountEvent event,
      Emitter<AuthenticationState> emit) {
    // delete user
    _auth.deleteUser();
    emit(AuthenticationFailureState(
        errorMessage: 'Deleted account, forcing sign out'));
  }
}

bool validFormFieldsRegister(String email, String password, String confirmPassword) {
  // validating email address
  final RegExp emailRegExp = RegExp(
    r'^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$',
  );

  // Check if email is valid
  if (!emailRegExp.hasMatch(email)) {
    return false;
  }

  // checking if passwords match
  if (password != confirmPassword) {
    return false;
  }

  // checking if password is long enough
  else if (password.length < 6) {
    return false;
  } else if (email.isEmpty) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

bool validFormFieldsLogin(String email, String password) {
  // validating email address
  final RegExp emailRegExp = RegExp(
    r'^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$',
  );

  // Check if email is valid
  if (!emailRegExp.hasMatch(email)) {
    return false;
  }

  // checking if password is long enough
  else if (password.length < 6) {
    return false;
  } else if (email.isEmpty) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

I am using a BlocProvider at the top of my widget stack and using a BlocNavigate class to navigate between screens. But I also have a router class for certain navigation:
main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>(
      create: (BuildContext context) => AuthenticationBloc()..add(AuthenticationInitialEvent()),
      child: const MyApp(),
    ));
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: const BlocNavigate(),
        onGenerateRoute: AppRouter().onGenerateRoute,
        title: 'ReceiptCamp',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ));
  }
}

class BlocNavigate extends StatelessWidget {
  const BlocNavigate({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
      listener: (context, state) {},
      buildWhen: (previous, current) {
        print('previous: ${previous.runtimeType}');
        print('current: ${current.runtimeType}');
        return previous != current;
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is AuthenticationLogoutSuccessState) {
          return const Login();
        }
        if (state is AuthenticationRegistrationFailedState) {
          return const Register();
        }
        if (state is AuthenticationEmailVerificationInProgressState) {
          return const EmailVerification();
        }
        if (state is AuthenticationSuccessState) {
          return const Home();
        } else {
          return const Login();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

app_router.dart

```
class AppRouter {
  Route onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => const Home(),
        );
      case '/register':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => const Register()
        );
      case '/login':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => const Login()
        );
      case '/verify':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => EmailVerification()
        );
      case '/explorer':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => const FileExplorer()
        );
      default:
        return _errorRoute();
    }
  }
}

Route<dynamic> _errorRoute() {
  return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Error"),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text('ERROR'),
        ));
  });
}
```

My register screen navigates to the email verification screen if the account can be created in firebase:

```
class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  const Register({super.key});

  @override
  State<Register> createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  // TextFormField state
  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  String confirmPassword = '';
  String error = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is AuthenticationFormErrorState) {
          print('state is AuthenticationFormErrorState');
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars();
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
              .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                content: Text('Please check your email and/or password'),
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),));
        } else if (state is AuthenticationNavigateToEmailVerificationState) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/verify');
          print('Navigating to EmailVerification');
        } else if (state is AuthenticationFailureState) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars();
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
              .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                content: Text('Failed to register'),
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),));
        } else if (state is AuthenticationSwitchScreenState) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/login');
        }
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            title: const Text('Register'),
          ),
          body: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 100),
            child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Container(
                      width: 250,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration:
                            textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'email'),
                        // value represents whatever is being typed into the form field
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            email = value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Container(
                      width: 250,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration:
                            textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'password'),
                        obscureText: true,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            password = value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Container(
                      width: 250,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration:
                            textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 're-enter password'),
                        obscureText: true,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            confirmPassword = value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          context.read<AuthenticationBloc>().add(AuthenticationRegisterButtonClickedEvent(email: email, password: password, confirmPassword: confirmPassword));
                        },
                        child: const Text('Register')),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Text(error,
                        style:
                            const TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 14)),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        child: const Text('Login instead'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          context.read<AuthenticationBloc>().add(AuthenticationSwitchScreenButtonClickedEvent());
                        }),
                  ],
                )),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

My Email Verification screen listens to the authentication bloc and navigates to the home page when a success state is emitted:

email_verification.dart

```
class EmailVerification extends StatefulWidget {
  const EmailVerification({super.key});

  @override
  State<EmailVerification> createState() => _EmailVerificationState();
}

class _EmailVerificationState extends State<EmailVerification> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // starting email verification timer
    context.read<AuthenticationBloc>().add(AuthenticationInitialEmailVerificationEvent());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is AuthenticationSuccessState) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/");
        } 
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            title: const Text('Verify'),
          ),
          body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text('Please check your email'),
              const SizedBox(height: 24),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Text('Resend verification email')),
              const SizedBox(height: 24),
              const Text(
                  'You have 300 seconds to click on the verified link in your email address'),
              const SizedBox(height: 24),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  context.read<AuthenticationBloc>().add(AuthenticationRegistrationCancelledEvent());
                }, 
                child: const Text('Cancel registration')),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I log out of the app using a listile in a NavDrawer which is part of my Home Screen

```
class NavDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavDrawer({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
      listener: (context, state) {},
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              const SizedBox(height: 100),
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.settings),
                title: const Text('Settings'),
                onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.border_color),
                title: const Text('Feedback'),
                onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                title: const Text('Logout'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  context.read<AuthenticationBloc>().add(AuthenticationLogoutButtonClickedEvent());
                },
              ),
              // temporary buttons for debugging
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                title: const Text('Delete all receipts'),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.print),
                title: const Text('Print all receipts'),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.delete_forever_rounded),
                title: const Text('Delete account'),
                onTap: () {
                  // implement delete account with bloc, requires sign in before
                  // deletion can be done
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        /*if (state is AuthenticationLogoutSuccessState) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/login', (route) => false);
        }
        */
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        switch (state.runtimeType) {
          case AuthenticationLoadingState:
            return const Scaffold(
                body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
          default:
            return Scaffold(
                drawer: const NavDrawer(),
                appBar: const HomeAppBar(),
                body: const Placeholder(),
                floatingActionButtonLocation:
                    FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
                floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  child: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                ),
                bottomNavigationBar: NavBar());
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I have used some print statements to track what states are being emitted and when the logout button is clicked the output is as follows. I am struggling to identify why `AuthenticationEmailVerificationInProgressState` is being emitted after `AuthenticationLogoutSuccessState`. I expect that since this logout success state has been emitted, the login screen should be displayed, as this state is being listened to by the BlocNavigate class

```
flutter: authenticationLogoutButtonClickedEvent()
flutter: stopEmailVerificationTimers()
flutter: previous: AuthenticationSuccessState
flutter: current: AuthenticationLoadingState
flutter: previous: AuthenticationLoadingState
flutter: current: AuthenticationLogoutSuccessState
flutter: {email, false}
flutter: {email, false}
flutter: previous: AuthenticationLogoutSuccessState
**flutter: current: AuthenticationEmailVerificationInProgressState
flutter: previous: AuthenticationEmailVerificationInProgressState
flutter: current: AuthenticationEmailVerificationInProgressState**
flutter: startEmailVerification()
flutter: authenticationCheckEmailVerificationStatusEvent()
flutter: {email, false}
flutter: previous: AuthenticationEmailVerificationInProgressState
flutter: current: AuthenticationEmailVerificationInProgressState
```